# How can I make ignore path with slash in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, apache2

Is there any way to get url like `http://example.com/ad/da` or `http://example.com/xx/zz` in one file (for example index.php located in root)?

I want to get these path `ad/da` or `xx/zz` and put into follow code located in root folder (index.php).

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.example2.com/?'.$upper_path);
```

In other word I want when user go to the `http://example.com/ad/da` URL I fetch `ad/da` and put into the follow code

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.example2.com/?'.$upper_path);
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but I think you are trying to look into **.htaccess** , but feel free to clarify more..

Comment: What have you tried, as previously stated it's not clear what you are looking to do. Example code or a more descriptive description using example data would probably gain more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following rule to your `.htaccess` in your website's root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Now all the requests coming in will be routed to `index.php` where you can retrieve the path as

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('http://www.example2.com/?'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
```

If you want this to happen for only certain URIs use this instead.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/ad/da)|(/xx/zz) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```